# Can i change count limit of versions for azure blob storage?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, blob, blobstore, blobstorage

By default one blob can have 1000 versions, but i need to storage only 10 versions. How can i do it?

I expected property or etc, for limit versions

Answer (score 0):

Well, you don’t need to store any more versions, than you want to! Ten is perfectly acceptable.

If you creates the versions. Therefore you can create as many versions as they want to, up to 1000.

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/versioning-enable?tabs=portal#list-blob-versions